# How can I remember to periodically check the minimap and resources?

Tags: starcraft-2

During the game, or battle, I always forget to look at the minimap, to spend free money or build a pylon. Maybe someone knows any application that will monitor this and will not be blacklisted by Blizzard. **I don't need cheat software** for which you can banned in battle.net. I need a way to increase my own skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know two such tools. Both of them based on [day 9 mental checklist](http://day9fan.com/category/d9d/mental-checklist) idea:

- [day 9 coacher](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=176737) that simply loops sounds
- [sc2drill](http://sc2drill.com) application. I recommend this one. It allows you to define independent notification loops for map / production /resources event. Plus this tool has "smart" mode ("score & notify" as I remember) to notify only when you stops to check you production buildings etc

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a kind of program that will monitor it for you.

**It's simply something that you'll have to practice.**

During the heat of battle it is difficult to manage these things. One of the things I did a few times was just to do a few practice games versus the AI and all I focused on was building units, checking supply, upgrading, etc. I rallied my buildings to the AI's base so they would keep getting killed. I kept a few units at home to make sure I didn't keep dying. It also helped my micro to try to survive with small armies.

Eventually it becomes part of your mental checklist and it will become part of your gameplay.

Comment: ...Why the downvote?

Comment: +1. "Just freaking practice it" is excellent advice. You can develop your own tricks to doing it, but if you are bad at something, focus on that thing, play some games against AI and just freaking practice it until it becomes second nature. No tool can give you an instinct.

Comment: Thanks tenfour, I thought I said something wrong when I got the down vote. No program can give you the skills you require to play Starcraft well. And as a secondary note, stuff like that isn't allowed in tournament style play so a built up reliance on a program to remind you to build pylons or spend money is a pretty bad habit to form.

Answer (score 0):

Cover your entire screen except the minimap and food count, so you will always look at the minimap and you will never psi block yourself :P 
hehe kidding, you have to get used to ALWAYS look the minimap, and bounce at the food count constantly. 
For spengind money, try watching Day[9]'s "steal a build" (#289) daily, it can really help.
You can find it on [day9.blip.tv](http://day9.blip.tv)

Answer (score -1):

One way to get better is turn on (or up) the in-game sounds which tell you when you are out of psi, or when "your forces are under attack" etc...  Every time you hear these reminders without being first aware of them, scold yourself (open-palmed face slap should work).  Eventually these things become second nature.  Somehow pylon timing is now ingrained in my brain, I almost cannot help but put them down when they are needed.

Comment: Good suggestion, it helped you while you are not 'heat' though.

Comment: Man, when it says "You need to build more pylons", you are already supply blocked... It's too late... I think no program can make you build pylons at the good time, only practice can.

Comment: dag, -1 huh?  I thought that was a decent suggestion, thats how I did it and I turned out all right...  My cannon rushes are unstoppable!!